# Recoding floats in a list

Tags: python, if-statement, floating-point

I have a list of floats, which looks like this:

```
predictions_dec = [13.0, 8.6, 4.9, -1.5, 6.2, 7.7, 2.0, 10.0, 7.7, 12.7,...]
```

I want to clean this data, by giving number higher than 10.0 a 10.0 and numbers lower than 0.0 (so all negative numbers) a 0.0. I'm doing this with the following if statement:

```
predictions_clean = []
for pred in predictions_dec:
    if pred >= 10:
        predictions_clean.append(10.0)
    if pred <= 0:
        predictions_clean.append(0.0)
    else:
        predictions_clean.append(pred)
```

This code seems to work, but the funny thing is that:

```
len(predictions_dec) 
1222
len(predictions_clean)
1816
```

My understanding of if statements is not that great. Where in the if statement am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is `ratings_dec` an example of a `predictions_dec`?

Comment: Yes, forgot to change it..

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace the second `if` with `elif`:

```
predictions_clean = []
for pred in predictions_dec:
    if pred >= 10:
        predictions_clean.append(10.0)
    elif pred <= 0:
        predictions_clean.append(0.0)
    else:
        predictions_clean.append(pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will append something for any number that is greater than 10.0 twice.

```
predictions_clean = []
for pred in predictions_dec:
    if pred >= 10: #e.g. 12, we append 10.0
        predictions_clean.append(10.0)
    if pred <= 0:
        predictions_clean.append(0.0)
    else:         #and now 12 is not less that 0, so append that
        predictions_clean.append(pred)
```

You want elseif

```
predictions_clean = []
for pred in predictions_dec:
    if pred >= 10:
        predictions_clean.append(10.0)
    elif pred <= 0:
        predictions_clean.append(0.0)
    else:
        predictions_clean.append(pred)
```

You can manage this with a list comprehsenion

```
predictions_clean = [0.0 if x < 0 else (10 if x > 10 else x) for x in predictions_dec]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is very large (and you thus want to avoid loops and `if` statements) you could also use NumPy and the mathematical trick to set every negative number to zero by:

```
A = .5*(A+np.abs(A))
```

You could do the same to set everything larger that 10 to 10. Here is everything put together:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([13.0, 8.6, 4.9, -1.5, 6.2, 7.7, 2.0, 10.0, 7.7, 12.7])

# set all items <= 0 to 0.0
A = .5*(A+np.abs(A))
print(A)

# set all items >= 10 to 10.0
A = 10.-A
A = .5*(A+np.abs(A))
A = 10.-A
print(A)
```

---

## Edit

The suggestion by "tobias_k" is of course better then mine. But to put some science into it I considered a random list/array of length 1,000,000. I compared the above implementation to

```
A[A< 0.] =  0.
A[A>10.] = 10.
```

and to the answer of "Miriam Farber". I found:

1. The approach with `A[A<0.] = 0.`, by "tobias_k", to be the fasted.
2. My approach took about twice as much time.
3. The approach with `if`-statements and the `for` loop, by "Miriam Farber", took about 50 times as much time. (This also approximately holds from the `min`, `max` construction in an inline `for`-loop, which is a bit faster: 42 times as much time as the fastest option.)

Comment: Isn't this looping the entire array _multiple_ times? (It might do so in C, though)

Comment: Yes... But using the compiled routines of NumPy. For large arrays this should be a big difference

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier then to use something like `A[A > 10] = 10.0` and `A[A < 0] = 0.0`?